# What are appropriate fields for a job board profile?

Tags: users, jobs, profile

I'm not sure if this fits quite into the category of UX, however I'm currently in the process of designing and developing a job board site for a specific industry which also gives employers the ability to look at the profiles/CVs of members/jobseekers who opt in.

To this end I'm wondering what information is relevant, and what fields could improve or even harm the chances of some job seekers?

For example should I give the option for a profile photo? Maybe some people might not want to provide this, could this harm there chances with some employers?

Also how could some fields be structured? Could employers search for expertise 'tags' such as UK design for example.

So far these are the fields that I am considering:

Name, career level/education level, expected pay range, preferred locations, expertise, years experience, CV (uploadable option), interests (not work related), job history.

I know this is a fairly broad question but some ideas would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

From a UX perspective, there should be one field:

- Your Resume

EDIT:

The point of my answer from a UX perspective is that a user already has a resume. The smoothest process is to upload that resume and be done with it.

There are things you can do with that resume. On one level, you can parse it out and let a user validate the sections. I've seen systems do this where you upload a resume, and then it shows you your 'work history' data, your 'address' data, etc.

So, I stand by that answer. From the end-user POV, don't ask them to replicate data they already have.

Now, let's look at the employer side. I'd suggest you really need to ask them directly about this. And then weigh their answers against the answers of the job seekers. And then depending on the objectives of the site, you may have to make compromises between the two sides.

To go through you example list really quick:

- Name: You should definitely ask for this field.
- career level/education level: should be on the resume
- expected pay range: this is where you need to compromise. Employers love this, job seekers usually do not (unless they are voluntarily demanding a minimum threshold). If the site is solely to benefit employers, maybe ask for this field. If it's to benefit the employee, maybe not.
- preferred locations: this is useful for the employee searching for jobs, but not useful for the employee who is wanting employers to find them. Instead, maybe ask 'willing to relocate' and leave it at that.
- expertise: in the resume
- years experience: in the resume, but also kind of a vague variable to begin with. It's somewhat arbitrary when an employer is looking for 'x years' experience.
- CV (uploadable option): yes! :)
- interests: I honestly have never found this to be useful info. But that's just me.
- job history: on the resume!

So, again, much of what is up there is on the resume. Ideally, you'd get that data directly from there as best you can.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @rk how does it not answer the question?

Comment: Although I understand the reasoning (the user should have the easiest ride possible) this is not a solution. This method would not provide any qualitative date or anything by which employers could filter candidates. I also don't think UX is about making things as easy as possible. Granted entering information into a job profile isn't fun but it is a means to an end and you need to put some effort in to get a good result from it.

Comment: I find it very bizarre that on a UX site, so many people would downvote the better UX.

Comment: @JoeTaylor I don't disagree with you that entering 'good info' can produce 'good results' but I'm not sure that's how job searchers work. Perhaps they do, and, if that's the case, you shouldn't be asking us this question, but those that are looking for employees. In my experience, most automated systems are mostly key word loggers, in which case, the resume is as good as any individual data fields.

Comment: @rk answer updated. Let me know if that's better.

Comment: also, @joetaylor I updated it to clarify my initial point. Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes much improved, I'm not entirely sure about the systems that pull data from CVs as they have always seemed a but flaky to me. I've always ended up correcting a majority of fields. The aim of the site is to provide an equally good service for both employers and job seekers so I'll have to weigh up my options.

Comment: @DA01 Just to remark, I didn't originally downvote this answer because it was a "worse UX". I downvoted it because there was no reasoning as to _why_ it was a better UX -- the idea of automatically extracting fields from the resume was non-obvious, at least to me. Now you've updated the answer with reasoning, I have upvoted the answer.

Comment: @DA01 It sounded more like a statement and less of an answer. The updated answer solves the issue. Thanks :)
p.s. As I have said earlier, I do not downvote people.

Comment: @Brendon good point. I should definitely have provided context.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would not try to reinvent the wheel.  Do some research on what the other big job boards do and why, then apply any industry-specific fields if applicable.